# App Crashes when Dismissing ProgressDialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am using `ProgressDialog` in my `WebView` app.
In `onPageStarted`, I show the dialog but when using `pd.dismiss` in `onPageFinished`, the app crashes.

```
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    //Opens all the Clicked Links in App itself.. (No Opera/Browser/Chrome/Uc popup)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    //Shows a Dialog when there is an Error
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorcode,String description, String fallingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"NetWork Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //Showing ProgressBar when Page is Loading
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view,String url , Bitmap favicon){
        ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pd.setMessage("Loading...");
        pd.show();

    }

    //Hiding ProgressBar when Loading Finished
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view,String Url){
            pd.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: add crash Logcat details here.

Comment: can you share your crash stacktrace ?? error log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it happens for nullPointerException. You need to make the ProgressDialog as an instance filed of that class and initialize it onCreate. Like the following:

```
private ProgressDialog pd;

@override
public void onCreate () {
    pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pd.setMessage("Loading...");
}
```

now when you need to show that just call show() method on that pd progressDialog and you can dismiss at any time by calling dismiss() method.

Answer (score 1):

ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

```
                 //Opens all the Clicked Links in App itself.. (No Opera/Browser/Chrome/Uc popup)
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

                //Shows a Dialog when there is an Error
                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorcode,String description, String fallingUrl) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"NetWork Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                //Showing ProgressBar when Page is Loading
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view,String url , Bitmap favicon){

                    pd.setMessage("Loading...");
                    pd.show();

                }

                //Hiding ProgressBar when Loading Finished
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view,String Url){
                        pd.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

It works for me.

Comment: You have declare ProgressDialog pd outside but not initialize. You have to initialize outside the method not in onPageStart().

Comment: Yes, I know that. You can [edit] your post to explain that in more detail, if your wish

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Declare it globally
 LinearLayout progressLayout;
```

**In the onCreate():**

```
 progressLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_refreshing_progress);
 wv_tandc.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
 wv_tandc.loadUrl(getString(R.string.terms_and_conditions_url));
```

Implement the WebViewClient :

```
  private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            System.out.println("on finish");
            progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }
```

Write the below code in your xml,**where you have defined your WebView:**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_refreshing_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sf_refreshing"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

You do not need to use `progressdialog`,instead you can use custom layout.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this, I assume `pd` is a member variable.

```
//Hiding ProgressBar when Loading Finished
public void onPageFinished(WebView view,String Url){
        pd.dismiss();
}
```

However, you seem to think this is assigning that same `pd` variable, but it isn't. See [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

```
//Showing ProgressBar when Page is Loading
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view,String url , Bitmap favicon){
    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pd.setMessage("Loading...");
    pd.show();

}
```

Remove `ProgressDialog` from `ProgressDialog pd =`, so just `pd = new ...`

Answer (score 0):

Declare `ProgressDialog` object as member variable

Comment: In `onPageStarted()` he is creating local object, it should be member variable.

Comment: I know. I'm saying that it is already a member variable, and *that* one should be initialized instead of creating the local one.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view,String Url){
          if(pd ! =null)                  
             pd.dismiss();       
      }
```

Comment: This avoids the problem, not fixes it

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
@Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view,String url , Bitmap favicon){
                    pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                    pd.setMessage("Loading...");
                    pd.show();

                }

                //Hiding ProgressBar when Loading Finished
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view,String Url){
                        pd.dismiss();
                }
```

and declare dialog object as

```
private ProgressDialog pd;
```